# Apache httpd logging

Tags: linux, apache-httpd

I have a couple of questions about Apache httpd logging on Scientfic Linux 7

Apache logging seems to be using some kind of hard-link from the configured logs directory **/etc/httpd/logs** to **/var/log/httpd** (although the directories are on separate filesystems?!?!)

If a file is created in **/etc/httpd/logs** it also appears in **/var/log/httpd**. The disk usage for "/" (where /etc/httpd/logs lives) does not increase but it does for "/var" (where /var/log/httpd)

I cannot see any references to any softlinks between files or directories in the 2 locations.

This output shows that both directories have the same inode reference:

```
lsof /var/log/httpd/
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
bash    5062 root  cwd    DIR    8,6       52 3271451 /etc/httpd/../..

lsof /var/log/httpd/
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
bash    5062 root  cwd    DIR    8,6       52 3271451 /var/log/httpd
```

This shows that the 2 directories should be on different filesystems.

```
df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        5109760 1170352   3939408  23% /
devtmpfs          933028       0    933028   0% /dev
tmpfs             942256       0    942256   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             942256   16928    925328   2% /run
tmpfs             942256       0    942256   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda8          98988    5328     93660   6% /home
/dev/sda5        1020588   32984    987604   4% /tmp
/dev/sda6        1020588  882452    138136  87% /var
/dev/sda7         201388   61384    140004  31% /support
/dev/sda9          47788   10080     37708  22% /var/log/audit
/dev/sda1         252588  153472     99116  61% /boot
tmpfs             188452       0    188452   0% /run/user/0
```

This shows the inode directory listing for the 2 directories:

```
ll -id /var/log/httpd /etc/httpd/logs/
3271451 drwx------ 2 root root 52 Jun 20 14:06 /etc/httpd/logs/
3271451 drwx------ 2 root root 52 Jun 20 14:06 /var/log/httpd
```

My 1st question is how is this configuration possible? I didnt think you could hard link across filesystems - is it possibly using some kind of **bind mount**?

My 2nd question is how can we stop Apache logging here? There is nothing at all in any of Apache's config files to reference logging under **/var**

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your `ll -id /var/log/httpd /etc/httpd/logs/` command has a / at the end so you're forcing a dereference of the symlink.  Do it without the / and you'll see /etc/httpd/logs is a symlink to ../../var/log/httpd or similar.  `ll -id /var/log/httpd /etc/httpd/logs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, hard links cannot span file system boundaries, though in this example there is a soft-link under /etc/httpd for the logs directory:

```
logs -> ../../var/log/httpd
```

These types of symbolic links can be by pathname that can span these boundaries. What you have described looks like the typical Red Hat/Scientific setup for Apache.

In the file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` you can verify the logging location, normally ErrorLog and CustomLog is setup, these can be changed. Though if you want to change all the logging to a single location you might want to change the symlink under `/etc/httpd`

Comment: Thanks for both replies - a softlink makes total sense. I just wasnt seeing it due to the trailing "/" as mentioned (d'oh!)